# S32K146EVB Read Collision when erasing/writing flash

Tags: c, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

when i try to erase or write to the program flash on my S32K146 EVB i run into a Fault at the moment the FTFC should execute the command. Also the RDCOLLERR bit in the FTFC_STAT register is set. This is the Error from S32DS:

BusFault: A precise (synchronous) data access error has occurred. Possible location: 0x00000BA0.

The PC stopped at 0xb8a.

This is the disassembly:

```
11          while ((FTFC->FSTAT & FTFC_FSTAT_CCIF_MASK) == 0);
00000b88:   nop     
00000b8a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; (0xba0 <execute_command+44>)
00000b8c:   ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
00000b8e:   uxtb    r3, r3
00000b90:   sxtb    r3, r3
00000b92:   cmp     r3, #0
00000b94:   bge.n   0xb8a <execute_command+22>
12          return;
00000b96:   nop     
13        }
00000b98:   mov     sp, r7
00000b9a:   pop     {r7}
00000b9c:   bx      lr
00000b9e:   nop     
00000ba0:   movs    r0, r0
00000ba2:   ands    r2, r0
```

Strangely enough this does not happen, when i step through the program line by line. Then the flash gets programmed correctly.

This is my routine for erasing a flash sector:

```
void flash_erase_section(unsigned int addr)
{
    // wrong address
    if ((addr > FLASH_END_ADDRESS && addr < FLEXNVM_START_ADDRESS) || addr > FLEXNVM_END_ADDRESS){
        return;
    }

    asm volatile("cpsid i");
    // wait if operation in progress
    while ((FTFC->FSTAT & FTFC_FSTAT_CCIF_MASK) == 0);

    // clear flags
    FTFC->FSTAT = FTFC_FSTAT_ACCERR_MASK | FTFC_FSTAT_FPVIOL_MASK;

    FTFC->FCCOB[3] = 0x09;                  // erase flash section command
    FTFC->FCCOB[2] = (addr >> 16) & 0xFF;   // address[23:16]
    FTFC->FCCOB[1] = (addr >> 8) & 0xFF;    // address[15:8]
    FTFC->FCCOB[0] = addr & 0xF0;           // address[7:0] 128 bit aligned
    execute_command();
    asm volatile("cpsie i");
    return;
}
```

The error happens in `execute_command()`:

```
void execute_command()
{
    FTFC->FSTAT |= FTFC_FSTAT_CCIF_MASK;
    while ((FTFC->FSTAT & FTFC_FSTAT_CCIF_MASK) == 0);
}
```

As mentioned earlier, this only happens when NOT debugging step by step. I suspect this has something to do with the flash being busy, but i did not find anything that would help me understand.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your right the FLASH is busy.  So which bit does the code need to test (in a loop) to wait for the FLASH to not be busy?

Comment: Thats the point. I couldnt find one. See my answer below for the probable cause of the problem.

Comment: The desired bit will be found in the `fstat` register.  Suggest reading the manual for the details of that register

Comment: to get started, suggest [reading}(https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/quick-reference-guide/S32K146EVB-QSG.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It seems that the MCU threw a Bus Fault because, by accessing the flash memory, the cached instructions became invalid. Disabling caching by writing `LMEM->PCCRMR = 0;` resolved the issue.

Nonetheless it would be interesting if there is a solution which doesn't include disabling caching alltogether.